# PHP - Display a code generated image recieved using curl as a gif

Tags: php, curl, get, gif

I have used a curl GET on a GIF image which was generated using a PHP script. If i echo out the image i get a load of text like this followed by a load of random characters:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK Date: Sat, 20 Dec 2014 11:01:27 GMT Server: Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu) X-Powered-By: PHP/5.5.9-1ubuntu4.5 Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0 Pragma: no-cache Content-Length: 6499 Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=100 Connection: Keep-Alive Content-Type: image/gif GIF87
```

How can i echo / display a regular gif image so i can see the image?

Comment: Show us the code you're using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Display it like this

```
<?php
header('Content-type: image/gif');
echo $image_content; // what you saw as random characters
?>
```

If you are getting the content from curl outputted on page, then disable the headers output and capture the characters provided by curl in a variable

```
$ch = curl_init(); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$image_content = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

Checkout the other options for curl here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php

Comment: also turn off CRLOPT_HEADER